Derivative error occured when installing PyQt6-tools
When I try to install PyQt6-tools the full output suggests that PyQt6-tools packages is avaliable, but depend on PyQt6-plugins which dosn't have any version avaliable. Here is the Error
ERROR: Cannot install pyqt6-tools==6.0.1.3.2, pyqt6-tools==6.0.2.3.2, pyqt6-tools==6.0.3.3.2, pyqt6-tools==6.1.0.3.2, pyqt6-tools==6.3.1.3.3 and pyqt6-tools==6.4.2.3.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    pyqt6-tools 6.4.2.3.3 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.4.2.3 and >=6.4.2.2.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.3.1.3.3 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.3.1.3 and >=6.3.1.2.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.1.0.3.2 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.1.0.3 and >=6.1.0.2.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.0.3.3.2 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.0.3.3 and >=6.0.3.2.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.0.2.3.2 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.0.2.3 and >=6.0.2.2.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.0.1.3.2 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.0.1.3 and >=6.0.1.2.2

Then I tried to install pyqt6-plugin alone, but it still says that there is not even a single version of it
$ pip3 install pyqt6-plugins --break-system-packages
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt6-plugins (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt6-plugins

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 Noble, Python 3.12.3, pip 24.2

pyqt6-plugins only has files up to python 3.11, so you might need to downgrade your python version

thank you very much, though I just find a way to bypass it, I'm not sure if I installed pyqt6-plugins though, but I clearly did install pyqt6-tools

I accidently found this way to install it instead using apt while trying to install otehr packages and got hind by ubuntu it self to do apt install pyqt6-dev-tools which solved the issue and replaced pip install PyQt6-tools
